# DataStreamer does not work well

Tags: ignite

I'm using Ignite 2.1.0 and I create a simple program to try DataStreamer, but I offen got error like this:
"[diagnostic]Failed to wait for partition map exchange" or "Attempted to release write lock while not holding it".
I started two local nodes, one was started in windows CMD using example xml configuration and another was started in Eclipse. My code in Eclipse like this :

```
public class TestDataStreamer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long bgn,end;
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
        CacheConfiguration<Long, Map> cacheConf = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConf.setName("TestDataStreamer").setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheConf.setBackups(0);
        IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConf);
        cache.clear();
        File dataFile = new File("D:/data/1503307171374.data"); //10,000,000 rows text data
        bgn = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            loadByStreamer(dataFile,ignite,"TestDataStreamer");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println((end-bgn)/1000.0+" s");
        }
        cache.destroy();
        System.out.println("cache destroy...");
        ignite.close();
        System.out.println("finish");
    }

    private static void loadByStreamer(File dataFile, Ignite ignite, String cacheName) throws Exception {
        IgniteDataStreamer<Long,TestObj> ds = ignite.dataStreamer(cacheName);
        //ds.allowOverwrite(true);
        ds.autoFlushFrequency(10000);
        ds.perNodeBufferSize(4096);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(dataFile),"UTF-8"));
        String line = null;
        long count = 0;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            ds.addData(System.currentTimeMillis(), parseData(line, Constants.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                    "id,sn,type_code,trade_ts,bill_ts,company_code,company_name,biz_type,charge_amt,pay_mode".split(",")));
            if(++count%10000==0){
                System.out.println(count+" loaded...");
            }
            //System.out.println(count+":"+line);
        }
        System.out.println("flushing...");
        ds.flush();
        System.out.println("flushed");
        br.close();
        ds.close();
        System.out.println("file handled...");
    }

    private static TestObj parseData(String data, String saperator, String[] fields){
        TestObj obj = new TestObj();
        if(data!=null && saperator.trim().length()>0){
            String[] values = data.split(saperator);
            obj.setId(values[0]);
            obj.setSn(values[1]);
            obj.setType_code(values[2]);
            obj.setTrade_ts(values[3]);
            obj.setBill_ts(values[4]);
            obj.setCompany_code(values[5]);
            obj.setCompany_name(values[6]);
            obj.setBiz_type(values[7]);
            obj.setCharge_amt(values[8]);
            obj.setPay_mode(values[9]);
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

class TestObj {
    private String id;
    private String sn;
    private String type_code;
    private String trade_ts;
    private String bill_ts;
    private String company_code;
    private String company_name;
    private String biz_type;
    private String charge_amt;
    private String pay_mode;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSn() {
        return sn;
    }
    public void setSn(String sn) {
        this.sn = sn;
    }
    public String getType_code() {
        return type_code;
    }
    public void setType_code(String type_code) {
        this.type_code = type_code;
    }
    public String getTrade_ts() {
        return trade_ts;
    }
    public void setTrade_ts(String trade_ts) {
        this.trade_ts = trade_ts;
    }
    public String getBill_ts() {
        return bill_ts;
    }
    public void setBill_ts(String bill_ts) {
        this.bill_ts = bill_ts;
    }
    public String getCompany_code() {
        return company_code;
    }
    public void setCompany_code(String company_code) {
        this.company_code = company_code;
    }
    public String getCompany_name() {
        return company_name;
    }
    public void setCompany_name(String company_name) {
        this.company_name = company_name;
    }
    public String getBiz_type() {
        return biz_type;
    }
    public void setBiz_type(String biz_type) {
        this.biz_type = biz_type;
    }
    public String getCharge_amt() {
        return charge_amt;
    }
    public void setCharge_amt(String charge_amt) {
        this.charge_amt = charge_amt;
    }
    public String getPay_mode() {
        return pay_mode;
    }
    public void setPay_mode(String pay_mode) {
        this.pay_mode = pay_mode;
    }
}
```

If stop the node started in CMD and run the program in only one node, it works well.
Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Which jdk version you use?

Comment: 1.8.0_144, 64-bit

Comment: are you sure that both nodes use the same version 1.8.0_144, 64-bit?

Comment: jdk 1.7 in Eclipse and 1.8.0_144 in WindowsCMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update jdk for both nodes to the same version, for example for 1.8.0_144(as you already have it in installed), or at least, try to update idk in eclipse to the latest of 1.7 versions, it should help.

There is a [thread on Ignite user list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Caused-by-org-h2-jdbc-JdbcSQLException-General-error-quot-java-lang-IllegalMonitorStateException-Attt-td15684.html), when guys faced pretty the same exception and updating of java version helped them to fix it.

Comment: I have tried using Linux in VM instead of windows CMD to start a node and both linux and Eclipse use jdk 1.8.0_144, it's OK. Thanks very much.